# How do I read response headers + body from single POST using scala's dispatch lib

Tags: scala, httpclient, scala-dispatch

I have been trying to use the [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/About) library to download a file via an http POST request. The server returns a "content-disposition" header suggesting a filename for the data file it returns.

I have succeeded reading the entire response body as a string,

```
http(r >~ { (x) => println(x.getLines.mkString("","\n","")) })
```

reading the response headers on their own

```
http(r >:> { (x) => println(x) })
```

and getting a BufferedReader for the response body

```
http(r >> { (x,c) => (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(x,c))).readLine })
```

How would I go about getting the response headers AND the response body in one go using the dispatch lib? The docs are very sparse and I am new to Scala.

TIA

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch uses Handlers to handle HTTP responses from a request.  It provides several handy shortcuts for performing routine tasks, like the ones that you outlined in the question such as generating an InputStream, returning the content as a string, or looking at the headers of the response.  There is also a method, [`>+`](http://github.com/n8han/Databinder-Dispatch/blob/master/http/src/main/scala/dispatch/Http.scala#L354), which composes two separate Handlers and executes them on the same request.  Here's how you could solve your problem using that handler:

```
val ret = http(req >+ { r => (r as_str, r >:> { _("Content-Disposition") }) })
```

The return value is a Tuple2 which contains, in this case, a string which is the content of the web page and another string which is the value of the Content-Disposition header.